# How to manage two fragments on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've an activity che contains a fragment, that I call fragment A.
When the screen is large enough, (layout-large) A shows two others fragment, B (a list of a products) and C (the details of the selected item from the list).
When the screen is not large enough, A shows only the fragment B, and when I click on some list item, it opens the fragment C with the selected product.

The problem is that when in portrait mode the fragment C is visible (the fragment vith details), if i change orientation, it comes back visible the fragment B (the list), but i would like to mantain the fragment C visible, in landscape mode.

How can i achieve this?

Here's some code:

**Large screen**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/book_list_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/book_details_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Normal screen**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/book_list_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And in the end the fragment A:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements ListFragment.onBookSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedIstance){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_fragments,container,false);
        /*drawer_fragments is the name of the layout that i've posted above*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            ListFragment listfrag = new ListFragment();
            FragmentManager fragManager = getChildFragmentManager();
            fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.book_list_content, listfrag).commit();
            if (view.findViewById(R.id.book_details_content) != null) {
                    /*Here if the screen is large enought to see also the details*/
                fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.book_details_content, new DetailsFragment()).commit();
            }
        }

    /*Other code...*/  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Fragment_One

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page_updated, null);
        frameLayout.addView(rootView);
        initUI();

        return frameLayout;
    }
```

and make onConfigurationChange()

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page_updated, null);
        frameLayout.addView(rootView);
        initUI();
    }
```

Comment: It behaves in the same way, maybe i have to put something particular inside initUI?

Comment: in initUI(), initialize all the TextView, Button and all.